# Validators before_update(ing) a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I want when editing a model to perform some validations so I thought that the best way is to use the

```
before_update
```

in Rails.

Can someone provide an example of a custom validator using a before_update call?

For example:

I have a class Topic and I want to allow only the creator of the Topic to be able to change the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Topic.rb
before_update :your_custom_validation

private
    def your_custom_validation
        # your code
    end
```

You can do that with any callbacks. That is, specify the filter and pass it a symbol to the name of your method.

You may also want to consider adding a user authentication gem like `devise` and only allowing logged in users to do stuff like that, which goes great with a permissions gem called `cancan`.

**Edit:** (Going to put it here too, even though it's in the comments below)
I forgot about order of execution. I would still recommend using something like devise and seeing if the right person is logged in (you can authenticate the user in the controller) or using the `validate :custom_method` callback to fire off with the other validations. If you're not the author, validations fail, nothing gets saved.

Comment: How can I check for a previous and the new value?? For existing value and the new value?

Comment: It won't work. You can't do validations on before_update because ActiveRecord already did checks for validations when it starts to call beffore_update. Take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#available-callbacks

Comment: so the only way is to check from the controller? before updating the model?

Comment: Ah thanks for the heads up @lucapette. I forgot about order of execution. I would still recommend using something like devise and seeing if the right person is logged in (you can authenticate the user in the controller) or using the `validate :custom_method` callback to fire off with the other validations. If you're not the author, validations fail, nothing gets saved.

Answer (score 1):

You could use http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#on the before_update comes after the validations fase in ActiveRecord. The link I just posted is very informative. You could use a custom validator with the on option.